# Python SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, pyopenssl

I'm getting an error when connecting to `www.mydomain.com` using Python 2.7.12, on a fairly new machine that uses Windows 8.1. The error is *`SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`* on the `ssl_sock.connect` line of the code below. The code wraps an SSL connection in an context, and specifies I don't want to carry out certificate verification:

```python
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
s_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s_, server_hostname=myurl)
ssl_sock.connect((myurl, int(myportno)))
```

I've tried adding the plain text version of the security certificate from the server I'm trying to connect to, to the default certificate file that Python references - that didn't work (in any case, it doesn't make sense that I should need to do this)

When I browse to the domain I'm trying to connect to, the browser also doesn't trust the remote server certificate, however I've examined the certificate that's bound to the domain and it's validating fine. What could be causing the mistrust? (I'm currently investigating removal of a Windows security patch from the machine where I'm getting the error, to see if that could be the cause)

(this issue has occurred on other computers using the same code, however it seems to resolve after Windows retrieves a full set of updates. The machine where the problem is persisting also has a full set of updates however)

Comment: Also see [Qualsys scan of www.appswiz.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.appswiz.com). It looks like an older IIS server. The trusted Root CA certificate for this site should be ***Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2*** with thumbprint 47beabc922eae80e78783462a79f45c254fde68b.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue, which seems to be related to a post Aug 29th 2016 security update for Windows that causes issues with certificate verification when using the TLS 1.0 protocol. Re-installing Windows without the security update at least allows things to work for now. Also I didn't get this issue when running under Windows 10

Comment: There is no such thing as a "TLS-1" certificate. There are TLS protocol versions (SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 .. TLS 1.2), there are ciphers (AES128-SHA,...) and there are certificates which are independent from the TLS protocol and mostly independent from the cipher. These certificates have signatures using SHA-1 (older) or SHA-256 (modern) and you probably refer to these. And I'm pretty sure that the python SSL stack on windows supports these so your problem is something different. Apart from that Python uses OpenSSL as the underlying SSL stack which is independent from the normal Windows SSL SChannel.

Comment: Thanks Steffen I've corrected my answer. It does seem that the security update is the most likely cause. I can only guess that there isn't complete independence of OpenSSL in relation to socket connection from a Windows machine.

Comment: There is also no "TLS-1" protocol. There are SSL 2.0 (totally insecure, mostly switched off), SSL 3.0 (insecure, often switched off), TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. But the validation of the certificate unrelated to the SSL protocol used so a protocol problem will not cause the validation fail. If the URL is public one might have a closer look at what the real problem is.

Comment: The only connection between the TLS stack of Python and the native TLS stack on Windows is that Python tries to use the Windows trust store by default. Thus if there is a different set of trusted certificates on the machine this might cause the certificate validation to fail. But this should be true for other clients using this trust store (i.e. Internet Explorer) too in this case and it looks like that this is the case. Are there any firewalls or antivirus doing SSL interception? What trust chain you see in the browser?

Comment: Thanks again Steffen. My understanding is that Python uses its own trust store by default. The domain is www.appswiz.com

Comment: The server does not look to bad. I suspect therefore that the validation problems are caused by something intercepting the SSL connection and thus replacing the certificate. Apart from malicious  man in the middle attacks this could be some SSL intercepting firewall in the network or a local antivirus product. Please check the certificate and chain you see in IE and compare it with the one you see on working systems.