# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED Error for python code running at AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

```
import krakenex
import decimal
import time

def now():
    return decimal.Decimal(time.time())

k_public=krakenex.API()
eth_ret = k_public.query_public('Ticker', req = {'pair': 'XETHZEUR', 'since': now()})
print(eth_ret)
```

The above python code is trying to make a request to an api services. Running it on a newly launched AWS EC2 instance (Windows Server 2012) gives the following error. There is no error when the code is running on another old instance, also with Windows Server 2012. Any advice to solve the problem? Many thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_kraken_ssl.py", line 9, in <module>
File "site-packages\krakenex\api.py", line 148, in query_public
File "site-packages\krakenex\api.py", line 130, in _query
File "site-packages\krakenex\connection.py", line 78, in _request
File "http\client.py", line 1107, in request
File "http\client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
File "http\client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
File "http\client.py", line 934, in _send_output
File "http\client.py", line 877, in send
File "http\client.py", line 1261, in connect
File "ssl.py", line 385, in wrap_socket
File "ssl.py", line 760, in __init__
File "ssl.py", line 996, in do_handshake
File "ssl.py", line 641, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719)
```

Comment: Can’t debug much without you providing the URL that is being accessed. Are both instances at the same update level? Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40857390/200603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by adding the domain of the api service website as trusted sites for Windows Server. Open Internet Explorer and go to Internet Options. Then under the Security Tab add something like http://*.yourdomain.com as Trusted sites.